# Download web page with one single click

Tags: javascript

I need to download hundreds of web pages manually. Unfortunately I can't automate the process since I don't know the urls of the web pages in advance. What I do now is open the page in browser, right click the mouse, select `save as` , choose a directory on my computer, and save the web page as html file.

It is just too much work since I need to repeat hundreds of times. It would be great if there's a floating button pops up when I open a page. When I click the button, the page will be saved to a default folder on my computer. I'll probably implement this function as a Chrome extension.

I guess this function can be easily realized with simple Javascript code. Unfortunately I have little experience with Javascript at all. It may take me quite a while whereas it's just a breeze for experienced web developers. Anyone help suggest the core lines of code I need to achieve this?

Comment: @MartinBean Why so that I can make my post clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task isn't best suited for Javascript since it doesn't have the ability to easily save files to your hard drive, in addition you will run into cross-domain issues likely. I would suggest an easy server side language like Go, PHP, or Python as you could set up a script to do this for you quite easily.

Comment: Can you be a little specific about the problems with Javascript? I need to implement this function as a browser extension since I may have to edit the web page content before actually saving it.

Comment: Javascript, as run in the browser, lacks the ability to save files to your harddrive, thus for a web-scraper it doesn't really suit it very well. It would not be hard to have Javascript make an AJAX call to a serverside script which would perform the task though.

Comment: Then I'm curious how the Firefox add-on Firebug implements the save button.